# Google Maps API v3 - list all open Infowindows

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

is it possible to get a list of all open infowindows? ie. like we can get for markers.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get a list of all markers in V3. A map has no idea about what markers are on it, only the marker knows which map it is bound to.

What you should do is create a array that you add the infowindows to when you open them and remove them when you close it.